# Get the parent entities from a join query

Tags: php, zend-framework2, inner-join

I have a many-to-one relationship between a `user_has_client` child entity and a `client` parent entity.

Here is the `user_has_client` table:

```
MariaDB [extrapack]> desc user_has_client;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| client_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I would like to return a list of `client` parent entities from a query involving the `user_id` of the `user_has_client` child entities.

I first tried this one:

```
 $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
 ->select('c')
 ->from('Application\Entity\UserHasClient', 'uc')
 ->innerJoin('uc.client', 'c')
 ->where('uc.user_id = :user_id')
 ->setMaxResults(10)
 ;
 $query->setParameters(array('user_id' => $user_id));
```

It gave me the following error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT c
   ': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.
```

And then tried this one:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
    "SELECT c.client_id
    FROM Application\Entity\UserHasClient u
    INNER JOIN u.client c
    WHERE u.user_id = {$user_id}");
```

And it gave me the same error:

```
Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT c FROM': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.
```

Comment: Is the relationship bidirectional? In other words does the client hold the inverse side of the relationship?

Comment: I thought it was not, but in fact it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the relationship is bidirectional you can use a query like this:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c')
    ->from('Application\Entity\Client', 'c')
    ->innerJoin('c.userHasClient', 'uc')
    ->where('uc.user_id = :user_id')
    ->setMaxResults(10);
$query->setParameters(array('user_id' => $user_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out about the users property on the client, meaning the relationship is bidirectional.

So I could then access the data with the following query:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
->select('c')
->from('Application\Entity\Client', 'c')
->innerJoin('c.users', 'u')
->andWhere("u.user_id = {$user_id}")
->orderBy('c.title', 'ASC')
->setMaxResults(10);
return $query->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```